# How to set selected image of UIButton in XCode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

I have two image sets for "flag" button in my Images.xcassets: flag-highlighted and flag-normal, where each set has 3 images of size x1, x2, x3

I use the flag-normal image set for the Image attribute in the attributes inspector for this button.  But, where/how do I specify the flag-highlighted image set for the selected state?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set image for specific button state via interface builder by using state config option.

[image: State config option]

Choose selected option and then pick your image for selected state.

Comment: That whole section of the inspector is missing by default now. See Gulfam's note above.

Answer (score 15):

If anyone is wondering why the state config is missing for button in xcode 13, you need to change button's style from plain to default after that state config  drop down will appear and you can change it to whatever you want

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Another brain-dead change from Apple: "Default" style is NOT the default.

Comment: Anyone know the reason I lose the Background Configuration section when I choose "Default"? I'm trying to use the Fill, Stroke, Corner Radius, etc, but also need the State Config.

(New to Swift and trying to just use IB for now if the answer is to do it in code)

Comment: @Alex did you try setting the background configurations after changing style to default?

Comment: @GulfamKhan I think so, but might be missing a step. When set to Default, all I get is a background image field. When setting to Plain, I have fields for Background, corner style, corner radius, fill, stroke, etc.
https://ibb.co/YPs9C73

The purple boxes are the area I'm seeing the difference and the right side being what I need. The dashed blue boxes at the bottom don't do exactly what I'm expecting, they change the entire button and don't give me corner radius or anything.

Comment: Well if you want to use state config, you can use default style and use UIView extension to add corner radius and other similar styling.

Comment: @GulfamKhan Thank you!! Super helpful in helping me google to find more of what I needed. I stumbled upon IBDesignable extension UIView which is letting me add some items to the attributes panel. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Alex Happy to halp